# Swap Website Title and Link URL in Google Search Results

Tags: jquery, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

This is part of the Google Search Results page source code. I want to move the div elements into the href container. In this case, I want to swap the first div.TbwUpd and last h3.LC20lb. So, I want this:

```php
<div class="g">
    <div data-hveid="CAMQAA" data-ved="2ahUKEwiy1bOI8IPlAhWVMN4KHfE2DXcQFSgAMAt6BAgDEAA">
        <div class "rc">
            <div class "r"> 
                <a href="https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meh" onmousedown="return>
                    <div class="TbwUpd">
                        <img class="xA33Gc" alt="https://www.merriam-webster.com/" height="16" src="data:image/png;base64,I=" width="16" data-atf="3"><cite class="iUh30 bc rpCHfe">Merriam-Webster › dictionary › meh</cite></div>
                    <br>
                    <h3 class="LC20lb">
                        <div class="ellip">Meh | Definition of Meh by Merriam-Webster</div></h3>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to become this:

```html
<div class="g">
    <div data-hveid="CAMQAA" data-ved="2ahUKEwiy1bOI8IPlAhWVMN4KHfE2DXcQFSgAMAt6BAgDEAA">
        <div class "rc">
            <div class "r"> 
                <a href="https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meh" onmousedown="return>
                    <h3 class="LC20lb">
                        <div class="ellip">Meh | Definition of Meh by Merriam-Webster</div></h3>
                    <br>
                    <div class="TbwUpd">
                        <img class="xA33Gc" alt="https://www.merriam-webster.com/" height="16" src="data:image/png;base64,I=" width="16" data-atf="3"><cite class="iUh30 bc rpCHfe">Merriam-Webster › dictionary › meh</cite></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to do that in this userscript but it didn't work.

```java
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Rearrange Goggle Search result :Swap Title and URL
// @include     https://www.google.com/search*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$('.TbwUpd').appendTo('.LC20lb');
```

[image: Original]

[image: After elements are swapped]

Comment: @boolfalse I guess this is the purpose of the question. The selected `div ` should be moved!

Comment: Yes, but the line break.. also the other container too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Google results are dynamically created so if that is the case, a whole lot of other code is needed to look for dynamic changes
2- There is no need to add a 700+ function long JQuery just for a tiny code. It would be a lot more efficient as pure JavaScript. (Note: JQuery 1 & 2 are deprecated as they had issues and should be avoided)
3- I am guessing there are more than 1 item to find and change so the fowling code will find all of them

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Rearrange Google Search result :Swap Title and URL
// @include     https://www.google.com/search*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

document.querySelectorAll('a div.TbwUpd').forEach(item => {
  item.parentNode.appendChild(item.nextElementSibling); // put the <br> at the end
  item.parentNode.appendChild(item);                    // put the <div> at the end
});
```

4- If it is only one item then

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Rearrange Google Search result :Swap Title and URL
// @include     https://www.google.com/search*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==


const div = document.querySelector('a div.TbwUpd');
div.parentNode.appendChild(div.nextElementSibling); // put the <br> at the end
div.parentNode.appendChild(div);                    // put the div at the end
```